# Rail - Return parents based on conditions of children, while eagerly loading children

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Foo
  has_many :bars
end

class Bar
  belongs_to: foo
end
```

This is an arbitrary example to get the question across.

Let's say any given `Bar` has one attribute: `age`. I'm looking to do an ActiveRecord query that returns **only** `foos` that **only** have `bars` where `age` is 7 (and no `bars` that don't match that condition), with those `bars` eagerly loaded.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Could you clarify: If a particular `foo` has a `bar` of age 7 and another `bar` of age 8, should this `foo` be in the result set or not?

Comment: Also could you clarify how to handle a `foo` that has 0 bars?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to go about this, but I think the most common would be this:

```
foos = Foo.includes(:bars).references(:bars).where("bars.age=7")
```

You can also do something like this to eliminate the join (this might be quicker for some data sets):

```
foos = Foo.includes(:bars).where("exists (select * from bars where foo_id=foos.id and age=7)")
```